# Views will not align or center vertically

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a class to which I need to add one or more Views. In this example, a single `ImageView`. 
I can add views without a problem and align them using `LayoutParameters`, but when I try to align or center them somewhere along the vertical axis, they either stick to the top or don't appear at all (they are likely just out of view). 
In the constructor I call a method `fillView()`, which happens after all dimensions and such are set.

**fillView()**

```
public void fillView(){
    img = new ImageView(context);
    rl = new RelativeLayout(context);

    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.device_access_not_secure);

    rl.addView(img, setCenter());
    this.addView(rl, matchParent());
}
```

**matchParent()**

```
public LayoutParams matchParent(){
    lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    lp.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
    return lp;
}
```

**setCenter()**

```
public LayoutParams setCenter(){
    lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE); //This puts the view horizontally at the center, but vertically at the top
    return lp;
}
```

Similarly, adding rules such as ALIGN_RIGHT or BELOW will work fine, but ALIGN_BOTTOM or CENTER_VERTICALLY will not.

I tried using both this method and the `setGravity()` a `LinearLayout` offers, with the same results.

Comment: Can you show us `matchParent()`? I suspect that your `RelativeLayout` isn't using the full screen size.

Comment: Added it to the question. I should note though, that I set the backgroundColor of the layout to green to see if it was on screen, and it filled the entire view, as it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I still don't know why my method worked horizontally, but not vertically, I did solve the problem. The posted methods worked, the problem was hidden in `onMeasure()`. 
I previously set the dimensions by simply passing them to `setMeasuredDimension()`. I fixed the issue by also passing them to the `layoutParams()`. I also changed the integers I used to `MeasureSpecs` while I was at it.

I changed this:

```
 @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
        super.onMeasure(this.getT_Width(), this.getT_Heigth());     
        this.setMeasuredDimension(desiredHSpec, desiredWSpec);
    }
```

to this:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec){
    final int desiredHSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(this.getT_heigth(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    final int desiredWSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(this.getT_width(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    this.getLayoutParams().height = this.getT_heigth();
    this.getLayoutParams().width = this.getT_width();
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(desiredWSpec);
    int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(desiredHSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
}
```

`getT_Width()` and `getT_Heigth()` are methods I used to get some custom dimensions I set elsewhere. 
I hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

You're adding your `ImageView` before you've added the `RelativeLayout`

Comment: I figured I was supposed to, since the image will show up if I use this order, but not the other way around.

Comment: I'm going to fire together a quick project and play around with this, give me ten minutes